# Unable to Install FB Prophet Using Conda (Mac OS)

Tags: python, anaconda

I am trying to install FB's Prophet package to use in Jupyter, which I launch via Anaconda, however I am getting errors with each attempt. I started on FB's Git [page](https://facebook.github.io/prophet/docs/installation.html#:%7E:text=to%20use%20prophet.-,Anaconda,%2Dc%20conda%2Dforge%20prophet%20.) and used 'conda install -c conda-forge prophet', however, I continuously get an error that I need to manually a series of files (hijri, ephem, lunarcalendar, etc.). I have researched as many links as I could, including this long exchange on [GitHub](https://github.com/facebook/prophet/issues/892), but have been unable to find a solution. In my more recent attempts to install Prophet I am just getting a continuous loop of "Solving environment".

I am a relatively new user to Anaconda and not intimately familiar with interacting in Terminal. If anyone can offer insights into what I could be doing differently it would be greatly appreciated.

Please let me know if I can provide any more details. Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried creating a new environment, rather than installing into the base environment (which already contains lots of packages, therefore causes you lots of dependency problems)? I.e. `conda create -n myenv -c conda-forge prophet jupyter` where `myenv` is whatever you want to call the environment.

Comment: I have not, though I think that could very work. Two additional questions: what CLI commands enable me to switch between environments? Secondly, would I need to change any operations within Anaconda to ensure Jupyter opened using the intended environment. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's always best to create a new environment rather than installing new packages into the base environment - the base env already contains lots of packages so you are liable to hit lots of dependency problems if you introduce anything new as `conda` tries to figure out what version of every package will be compatible with all the others.

To create a new env called `myenv` in which you want to use the packages `prophet` and `jupyter` (and all their dependencies), and getting the packages from the `conda-forge` channel, do:

```
conda create -n myenv -c conda-forge prophet jupyter
```

To use Jupyter in this environment, just activate the env before starting Jupyter:

```
conda activate myenv
jupyter notebook
```

For more information about working with conda environments, see [the documentation](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html)